# Deserializing QByteArray to multiple QVariantMap's

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, ipc

I'm using QTcpSockets for IPC. I thought I have some issue with QTcpSocket readyReady signal emission. Turns out I have an issue with QTcpSocket buffering.

In normal case there is a real simple piece of code to deserialize QByteArray into a QVariantMap

```
    // Init Last Buffer
    QByteArray lastBuffer;

    // ...

    // Init New Data Stream
    QDataStream newDataStream(lastBuffer);
    // Init Last Data Map
    QVariantMap lastDataMap;        

    // Clear Last Variant Map
    lastDataMap.clear();

    // Red Data Stream To Data Map
    newDataStream >> lastDataMap;
```

All work really nicely, until I send thru a lot of my packages fast. Turns out QTcpSocket packs those up into bigger package(s). Sometimes I receive all data into one QByteArray, sometimes separately into different size packages, definitely not the way the packages were actually written/sent at the other side.

My question is: any of you had the same issue? is there already a solution? can you recommend a good solution for this?

Of course I can go and dig all relevant Qt source, but my point is in my project to have an easy but sophisticated enough solution reusing already existing Qt components with only a reasonable amount of effort put into customization, development and changes. Innovation ; )

Thanx all!

Comment: In the meanwhile I had an idea to frame the packages. Basically add the same pattern/ID/descriptor at the beginning and the end of each package, then parse those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because TCP is a streaming protocol, meaning that data will arrive at your computer in varying chunks and be presented to your application as, and when, a new chunk arrives. `QTcpSocket` conforms to this specification so you cannot be guaranteed that, when it signals that data has arrived, that the data is complete.

Unfortunately, `QDataStream` makes the assumption that the device it's reading from contains a complete set of data. If `QDataStream` runs out of data to read, it will exit with undefined results, it will not wait for the next `QVariant` to finish downloading.

For this reason, you cannot use `QDataStream` on `QTcpSocket` like you would on other devices that have a complete set of data, such as `QFile`.

You need to build extra processing into your programs to check if enough data has arrived to parse.

If you look in the documentation at the Fortune Client and Fortune Server examples, you'll see that they've serialised the data using `QDataStream` first to a `QByteArray`, and then prepended the size of the data when sending across the network.

The client firstly waits till enough data has arrived to read the size of the data stream, then it keeps storing the incoming data in a `QByteArray` till everything has arrived before handing it over to `QDataStream` for parsing.

This method is fine if you're not transmitting a lot of data every time, or you're happy that you have enough memory resources to temporarily hold the data in a `QByteArray` till it's ready to be parsed.

If you need to parse as the data comes in, it would be recommended that you create your own custom protocol for streaming over the network, instead of QDataStream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the meanwhile I've found a solution as I wrote in my comment. Very simply I just add some unique descriptor at the beginning and the end of the data packets. Works nicely. If anyone interested can check the wop code @ https://github.com/maxavadallat/mcworker/blob/master/src/mcwfileserverconnection.cpp line 301 parsing data starts @ https://github.com/maxavadallat/maxcommander/blob/master/src/remotefileutilclient.cpp line 826. The code is far from ready, but shows what I meant.